# iptables: How to "override" a port redirect?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables

My setup is as follows:

I have a Linux server with two interfaces, `eth0` and `eth1`. `eth1` has an Internet connection through my normal LAN. `eth0` is serving DHCP and the interface itself has an IP address of `10.0.0.1`.

I want to accomplish the following:

I want to have packets on port 80 originating from machines connected to `eth0` to be redirected to port 80 on the routing machine itself, and response packets to of course be redirected back. That in itself is simple enough, but I have one more requirement. I would like clients on `eth0` with certain IP addresses to be able to be exempt from this, and have port 80 packets routed as they normally would be. How can I do this? So far, I've done the following to redirect all port 80 packets from `eth0` to the local machine. It is working, but I do not know how to do my second requirement.

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:80 -i eth0`

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just exit the `PREROUTING` table before it gets to the `DNAT` line:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -s <exempt ip> -j RETURN
```

This should insert (`-I`) a new rule to exit (`-j RETURN`) the routing table for any packet from the exempt IP (`-s <exempt ip>`) as the first rule, so it is hit before it gets to the `DNAT` rule.

(You might also need to do something similar on `POSTROUTING`, not sure.)

---

The other option is to create an IP set (`man ipset`) for the IPs that you want to exempt, and then add a inverted match to your `DNAT` and `SNAT` rules:

```
ipset create exempt hash:ip
ipset add exempt <exempt ip 1>
ipset add exempt <exempt ip 2>
ipset add exempt <exempt ip 3>
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -m set ! --match-set exempt src -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:80 -i eth0
```

This is easier to manage because you can easily add or remove exempted IPs from the ipset without modifying iptables.

Comment: This seems to have worked, but one more thing... How can I remove this rule?

Comment: You can remove the rule with `iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING 1` (where `1` is the index into the `POSTROUTING` chain of the rule you want to remove. Use `iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING` to list all the rules in the `POSTROUTING` chain.